# D3js exit() and update working, can't enter()

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a scatter plot with D3 and I'm trying to add circles to a selection based on changing data. I'm passing the data selection down to two functions: `render` and `update`. The `render` function is the initial render and `update` has the `enter()` and `exit()` methods. I can easily add the initial data set and get the circles no longer in the data set to exit. I'm using `d.id` as the d3 placeholder.

The problem: when I try to `enter()` the added data points, nothing happens. I've checked the length of the new data selection, and it's larger than the pre-existing. On the DOM, the smaller data set remains (the `circle`s that were already there), but no new circles enter, even though the data set has changed.

I've looked through lots of tutorials regarding data joins, and I think I've appropriately called my `enter()` and `exit()` methods. What gives?

Here is my code:

```
            var container = angular.element(document.querySelector('.chart-container'))[0];
            var margin = {
                    top: container.clientHeight / 12, 
                    right: container.clientWidth / 14, 
                    bottom: container.clientHeight / 10, 
                    left: container.clientWidth / 11
                };
            var w = container.clientWidth - margin.left - margin.right;
            var h = container.clientHeight - margin.top - margin.bottom;

            // ******** **************** ******** //  
            // ******** INITIAL RENDER ******** //
            function render(input) {

                console.log(Object.keys(input).length);

                var xScale = d3.scale.linear()
                    .domain([0, d3.max(input, function(d) { return d["ctc"]; })])
                    .range([0, w])
                    .nice();

                var yScale = d3.scale.linear()
                    .domain([0, d3.max(input, function(d) { return d["ttc"]; })])
                    .range([h, 0])
                    .nice();

                var rScale = d3.scale.linear()
                    .domain([0, d3.max(input, function(d) { return d["effective"]; })])
                    .range([2, 15]);

                // *********** //
                // SVG ELEMENT //  
                var svg = d3.select('.chart-container')
                    .append('svg')
                    .attr('class', 'scatter')
                    .attr('viewBox', '0, 0, ' + Math.round(w + margin.left + margin.right) + ', ' + Math.round(h + margin.top + margin.bottom))
                    .attr('preserveAspectRatio', 'xMinYMin')
                    // used to center element and make use of margins
                    .append('g')
                    .attr('transform', 'translate(' + margin.left + ',' + margin.top + ')');

                // add circles in group
                var circles = svg.append('g')
                    .attr('class','circles')
                    .attr('clip-path','url(#chart-area)');

                // add individual circles
                var circle = circles.selectAll('circle')
                    .data(input, function(d) {return d.id;})
                    .enter()
                    .append('circle')
                    .attr('class', 'circle')
                    .attr('cx', function(d) { return xScale(d["ctc"]); })
                    .attr('cy', function(d) { return yScale(d["ttc"]); })
                    .attr('r', function(d) { return rScale(d["effective"]); })
                    .attr('fill', function(d, i) { return d["effective"]; })
                    .on('mouseover', function(d) {
                        tooltip.style('visibility', 'visible');
                        return tooltip.text(d["technology"]);
                     })
                    .on("mousemove", function(){ return tooltip.style("top",
                        (d3.event.pageY-10)+"px").style("left",(d3.event.pageX+10)+"px");})
                    .on("mouseout", function(){return tooltip.style("visibility", "hidden");})


                // append clip path
                svg.append('clipPath')
                    .attr('id','chart-area')
                    .append('rect')
                    .attr('class', 'rect')
                    .attr('x', 0)
                    .attr('y', 0)
                    .attr('width', w)
                    .attr('height', h);

            };

            // ******** **************** ******** //  
            // ******** UPDATE ******** //
            function update(updateObject) {

                var input = updateObject;

                var xScale = d3.scale.linear()
                    .domain([0, d3.max(input, function(d) { return d["ctc"]; })])
                    .range([0, w])
                    .nice();

                var yScale = d3.scale.linear()
                    .domain([0, d3.max(input, function(d) { return d["ttc"]; })])
                    .range([h, 0])
                    .nice();

                var rScale = d3.scale.linear()
                    .domain([0, d3.max(input, function(d) { return d["effective"]; })])
                    .range([2, 15]);

                var svg = d3.select('svg')
                    .data(input)
                    .attr('viewBox', '0, 0, ' + Math.round(w + margin.left + margin.right) + ', ' + Math.round(h + margin.top + margin.bottom))
                    .attr('preserveAspectRatio', 'xMinYMin')
                    .append('g')
                    .attr('transform', 'translate(' + margin.left + ',' + margin.top + ')');

                // BIND TO DATA
                var circles = d3.selectAll('circle')
                    .data(input, function(d) { return d.id; });

                // Circles Enter
                circles.enter()
                    .insert('svg:circle')
                    .attr('class', 'circle')
                    .attr('cx', function(d) { return xScale(d["ctc"]); })
                    .attr('cy', function(d) { return yScale(d["ttc"]); })
                    .attr('r', function(d) { return rScale(d["effective"]); });
                    /*
                    .on('mouseover', function(d) {
                        tooltip.style('visibility', 'visible');
                        return tooltip.text(d["technology"]);
                     })

                    .on("mousemove", function(){ return tooltip.style("top",
                        (d3.event.pageY-10)+"px").style("left",(d3.event.pageX+10)+"px");})
                    .on("mouseout", function(){return tooltip.style("visibility", "hidden");})
                    */

                // UPDATE
                circles.transition()
                    .duration(1000)
                    .attr('cx', function(d) { return xScale(d["ctc"]); })
                    .attr('cy', function(d) { return yScale(d["ttc"]); })
                    .attr('r', function(d) { return rScale(d["effective"]); });


                // EXIT
                circles.exit()
                    .transition()
                    .duration(500)
                    .attr('r', 0)
                    .style('opacity', 0)
                    .style('fill', 'gray')
                    .remove();      

            }
```

**Update**
here is a codepen for testing: http://codepen.io/himmel/pen/JdNJMM

Comment: the use of `enter()` seems to be correct i guess, could you create a fiddle/snippet or something for testing?

Comment: I'm creating one now, will update soon.

Comment: By the way, it is always a good idea to use a `d3.scale.sqrt()` for the radius of circles, because with `d3.scale.linear()` the area of the circle is not proportional to the value ;)

Comment: I actually have read that area is better than radius, I plan to change once I can get the data bound with the circle elements - good looking out though. I'm trying to create a codepen to demonstrate my problem, but I'm weirdly having the same issue with `circle` elements not appending to the `g`. http://codepen.io/himmel/pen/JdNJMM

Comment: I just updated the codepen from my answer to include a call to the update function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with the code is, that you are trying to use an object as data. `d3.selection.data()` takes an array, not an object. See [the d3 wiki](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#data) for more information on the `data()` function.

I have created an [updated](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GJmEQz) version of your codepen. I changed the data to an array and applied the correct [conventional margin](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3019563). Moreover I simplified the code by removing the double initialization of scales and the svg element.

Comment: So, in my initial posting, the likely problem was that rather than having objects (w/out hash keys) inside of an array, I had objects, with hash keys, inside of an object?

Comment: exactly. as explained in my answer you can't use `data()` with an object. it has to be an array.

Comment: however there are other problems with your code. for instance you create a second svg in the update function instead of using the one already created. That's what i meant with double initialization.

Comment: Just for academic interest, you can add a `length` property to the data object and assuming all the other problems are fixed, it will work fine.  d3 only needs an "array like object" to bind data successfully.  Of course the `length` property would need to be managed manually.